# Import users with specific ID

Tags: import, plugin-import

Is it possible to use the saveUser method to import users with an existing ID?

```
craft()->users->saveUser($userModel)
```

I need to import 2000+ users and when doing so, I need to make sure that their old ID doesn't change after inserted, because I need to import other tables too and match them based on that.

The excellent import plugin tries to update the users instead of creating new ones when I tell it to import the ID as well. I'm not sure if that's intended behavior or a bug.

Answer (score 1):

If the `UserModel` contains a user ID, then the existing user will be *updated*.

If the `UserModel` does not contain a user ID, then a new user will be *created*.

Either way, the `UserModel` will contain an ID after being saved. Since models in PHP are passed by reference, the ID will get set automatically for new users.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that's not the question. I want a newly created user to have exactly the same ID as it was in the previous database.

Comment: Ah, that was not clear in the original question.

Comment: And if I guess right it's not doable?

Comment: It's probably doable, but complicated. I'll let someone else take a shot at answering that.

Comment: I think I'll do a surgical fix: add back the new user ID-s to the old tables and export them with the fresh ID-s :) Ugly, but only needs to be done once.